# HQL hibernate jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, thymeleaf

I have an HQL query from my repository and I want to get information from my class where condition class type = string. The error is `field is not present.`

**View:**

```
<div layout:fragment="content">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Mes demandes</div>
             <div class="panel-body">
             <form th:action="@{/demande}" method="post">
               <div>
                 <label>Type de la demandes:</label>
                 <select name="field">
                      <option th:value="Demande_absence">Demande d'absence</option>
                      <option th:value="Demande_conge">Demande de congé</option>
                      <option th:value="Demande_document">Demande de documtents</option>
                      <option th:value="Demande_pret">Demande de prêt</option>
                </select>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Chercher</button>
               </div>
             </form>
         <form th:action="@{/AddDemande}" method="post">    
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter une demande</button>
          </form>

       <div class="container-fluid spacer50">
        <h3 class="text-danger">Liste des demandes</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th><th>date</th><th>TYPE_DEM</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="p:${listdemandes}">
                    <td th:text="${p.codeDemande}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${p.dateDemande}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${p.class.simpleName}"></td>
                    <td><a th:href="@{/afficher(id=${p.codeDemande})}">Informations sur la demande</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
             <div class="text-danger" th:if="${exception}" th:text="${exception.message}">
             </div>

             <div class="container col-sm-8">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
               <li th:class="${pageCourante}==${status.index}?'active':''" th:each="pa,status:${pages}" >
                 <a th:href="@{demande(page=${status.index},size=${size})}" th:text="${status.index}"></a>
               </li>
              </ul>
 </div> 
          </div>
         </div>

    </div> 
 </div>
```

**Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/demande")      
public String dem(Model model,
                  @RequestParam(name="page",defaultValue="0")int p,
                  @RequestParam(name="size",defaultValue="4")int s,
                  @RequestParam(name="field",defaultValue="4")String type) {

    String pr_emp;
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Long matricule =Long.parseLong(auth.getName());

    pr_emp=employeRepository.prenom(matricule);
    Page<Demande> PageDemande=demandeRepository.listdemande(matricule,"valide",type,new PageRequest(p,s));
    int[] pages = new int[PageDemande.getTotalPages()];

    model.addAttribute("pages", pages);
    model.addAttribute("size", s);
    model.addAttribute("pagecourante", p);
    model.addAttribute("prenom", pr_emp);
    model.addAttribute("matricule", matricule);
    model.addAttribute("listdemandes",PageDemande.getContent());

    return "demandes";
}
```

**Repository Query:**

```
@Query("select d from Demande d where d.employe.matricule=:x and d.valide=:isvalide and d.class=:type order by dateDemande")
public Page<Demande> listdemande(@Param("x") Long matricule,
                                 @Param("isvalide") String isvalide, 
                                 @Param("type") String type, 
                                 Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: And also `Demande`?